# WP7 - Fast app switching and Internet Connection

Tags: windows-phone-7, internet-connection, fast-app-switching

Example:

My application is doing a HTTP Connection. 
If I change to home screen using Home Button (fast app switching) the connection that my application was doing is canceled.

Why?

Are there some way to avoid it?

Comment: How are you making the connection? Most classes like HttpWebRequest will be canceled when the app is deactivated.

Comment: I am using HttpWebRequest. Are there some way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately (or depending on how you look at it, fortunately, since it saves battery life), when an app is deactivated due to a home button press, most HTTP connections will be canceled, and most operations suspended. This code from [this blog post](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2012/01/11/httpwebrequest-webclient-and-tombstoning-in-windows-phone-7/) would check as to whether or not an HttpWebRequest was canceled by app deactivation (tombstoning):

```
    try
    {
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(MyResultAsync);
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
            MessageBox.Show("Looks like your request was interrupted by tombstoning");
        else
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("I got an http error of: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

If you want to download / upload a file in the background, you can take a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). For any more complex types of network operations, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to avoid this. When you Fast-App-Switch all your web requests will be cancelled.

If it was cancelled you'll be able to detect this in the exception you get when returning to the app:

```
catch (WebException webEx)
{
    if (webEx.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
    {
        // Retry request
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle other exception 
    }
}
```

If your application has other ways of (manually) cancelling requests then you'll need to account for these as well.